# How to cause static error in constexpr if-else chain?

Tags: c++, constexpr, c++20, static-assert, if-constexpr

In the following C++20 function template:

```
template<int i>
void f() {
    if constexpr (i == 1)
       g();
    else if constexpr (i == 2)
       h();
    else
       ??? // <--error
}
```

Is there something we can write in `???` such that a call of `f<3>()` will fail at compile-time?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is that the discarded statement of [constexpr if](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/if#Constexpr_If) can't be ill-formed for every possible specialization. [[temp.res.general]/6](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/temp.res#general-6)

(emphasis mine)

> The validity of a template may be checked prior to any instantiation.
>
> The program is ill-formed, no diagnostic required, if:
>
> - no valid specialization can be generated for a template or **a
>   substatement of a [constexpr if](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/stmt.if#def:constexpr_if) statement** within a template and the
>   template is not instantiated, or

You can use a type-dependent expression that is always `false`. E.g.

```
template<int i> struct dependent_false : std::false_type {};

template<int i>
void f() {
    if constexpr (i == 1)
       g();
    else if constexpr (i == 2)
       h();
    else
       static_assert(dependent_false<i>::value, "Must be 1 or 2");
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The standard idiom for this is to have a dependent template, that is specialized to `std::false_type`, like this:

```
template<int T> struct dependent_false : std::false_type {};
```

and then you can do:

```
template<int i>
void f() {
    if constexpr (i == 1)
       g();
    else if constexpr (i == 2)
       h();
    else
       static_assert(dependent_false<i>::value, "i can only be 1 or 2"); 
}
```

---

The reason you can't just say

```
static_assert(false, "i can only be 1 or 2");
```

is a rule in the language that says a branch of an `if constexpr` can't be false for *every* possible instantiation of the enclosing template.

Adding a template that *could* be specialized for `std::true_type` gets around this limitation.

Comment: Note that [a DR](https://cplusplus.github.io/CWG/issues/2518.html) _does_ allow `static_assert(false);` now, although you still have to avoid the instantiation being invalid for all template arguments for some _other_ reason.

Answer (score 1):

Just write

```
template<int i>
void f() {
    if constexpr (i == 1)
       g();
    else {
       static_assert(i == 2);
       h();
    }
}
```

which requires rewriting only the last condition.

Comment: This is the best suggestion because it does not require additional template (dependent_false).

Answer (score 0):

For the reasons given in the other answers, I would rewrite in the following way:

```
template<int i>
void f() {
    static_assert(i == 1 || i == 2, "must be 1 or 2");
    if constexpr (i == 1)
       g();
    if constexpr (i == 2)
       h();
}
```

In this way, you can avoid the class template.

Comment: A worthy thought, but in the real world code there are many more branches in the if-else chain and the condition expressions are more complex, and so you're suggested solution has a DRY violation in that the conditions all have to be repeated twice (once in static assert and once in condition).

Comment: @AndrewTomazos Before this sort of DRY violation becomes worrisome, I would consider whether "one `f` does different things for different values of `i`" is the right pattern.

Comment: Every if-else chain is a statement that does different things for a set of mutually exclusive conditions. ;)

Comment: As C++20, `template <int i> void f() requires (i == 1) { g(); } template <int i> void f() requires (i == 2) { h(); }` :-) But I would probably go for tag dispatching `void f(std::integral_constant<int, 1>) { g();} template <int i> void f() { f(std::integral_constant<int, i>{}); }`.

Comment: @Jarod42: Now you have a DRY violation in repeating the function template declaration `template<params> R f(params)` N times, rather than just once. ;)

Comment: If using overloads instead of using `if constexpr` is a DRY violation, yes. Else I don't really see repetition. (We might still compare lenght of written code, but that is another story IMO :-) ).